# How to get current orientation of device programmatically?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, orientation

I want to know the device orientation, I used

```
 UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation
```

but this only works when I change the orientation otherwise it does not give anything (TRUE/FALSE).So how can I get current device orientation even when orientation is not changed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

To get orientation

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```

and the possible orientations are

```
typedef enum {
  UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait           = UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
  UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown = UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
  UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft      = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft,
  UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight     = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight
} UIInterfaceOrientation;
```

Comment: I think this will work only when we change orientation. I want to create UI based on orientation (the initial orientation.)

Answer (score 4):

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```

Gives an Implicit Enumeration Warning.

Use this instead:

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```

Comment: You should not use UIDeviceOrientaiton for configuring things related to interface orientation. The reason is because UIDeviceOrientation specifices UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp and UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown values, which have no sense when applying them to UI. UIInterfaceOrientation is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if you've already done this, but have you looked into the **beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications** method, which enables notification generation for the device?

Also, are you looking for the **device** orientation or the **interface** orientation? If you're looking for a simpel Portrait vs Landscape orientation info, you should look into the interfaceOrientation of the view controller.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This notification will get called when we change orientation?But I want orientation even when orientation is not changed.

Comment: Hi again Deepak; Yes; as I've seen it, you can simply access the interfaceOrientation property and it will return a typedef of one of the possible orientations defined under UIInterfaceOrientation.

Comment: Thanks Madhumal, I got the solution.Using statusbar orientation we can find out current orientation.It solved my problem.